# Psycopg2 ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near SELECT

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, psycopg2, psql

Trying to pass a variable to a psql query. Code below. I'm ultimately trying to copy the results to a CSV file and an error occurs trying to execute the module cur.copy_expert.

```
date1 = ('2019-05-06',)
query = ('''SELECT * FROM product WHERE (product.esb_timestamp > %s AND product.esb_timestamp < '2019-05-11')''', date1)

# Copy the results to a new file
output = "COPY ({0}) to STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(query)
with open('Database_Query.csv', 'w') as file1:
    cur.copy_expert(output, file1)
```

Error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database_query.py", line 55, in <module>
    cur.copy_expert(output, file1)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ""SELECT * FROM nwwproduct WHERE (nwwproduct.esb_timestamp > %s AND nwwproduct.esb_timestamp < '2019-05-11')""
LINE 1: COPY (("SELECT * FROM nwwproduct WHERE (nwwproduct.esb_times...
```

Comment: Get rid of the brackets, change the quotation marks to `"` for clarity, and pass the single argument as a tuple: `query = ("""SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.esb_timestamp > %s AND product.esb_timestamp < '2019-05-11'""", (date1,))`. Does that work? If not, swap `%s` for `?`; I can't be sure on the binding parameter expected here.

Comment: Restructuring the brackets results in the same error, as does using `?`.

Comment: You replaced the entire line of code with a copy/paste of my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, copied and pasted.

Comment: I'm at a loss then. Can you please edit in the traceback from my suggestion?

Comment: According to this answer from postgresql.org, COPY doesn't support parameters. [link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+mi_8aPZX1nXWSD8UyML2csscmm9fK6KpQnBhfLdQ3T=bkAxw@mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) mentions

> If you need to compose a COPY statement dynamically (because table,
>   fields, or query parameters are in Python variables) you may use the
>   objects provided by the psycopg2.sql module.

This is also confirmed from this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/529#issuecomment-286913554) by one of the psycopg2 authors and current maintainer: @dvarrazzo.

```
from psycopg2 import sql

stmt = """COPY (SELECT * FROM product 
                WHERE (product.esb_timestamp > {dt} 
                  AND  product.esb_timestamp < '2019-05-11')
               ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER"""

query = sql.SQL(stmt).format(dt=sql.Literal("2019-05-06"))

with open('Database_Query.csv', 'w') as file1:
    cur.copy_expert(query, file1)
```

Do be aware this is different from Python's `str.format` and safely interpolates values to prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

COPY does not support parameters. [Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+mi_8aPZX1nXWSD8UyML2csscmm9fK6KpQnBhfLdQ3T=bkAxw@mail.gmail.com)